# get this data of row by click on button which is in row javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get all data of particular row by clicking in button in row in javascript.. here is my code in code pen.. like i press button on first row, i would get all data of first row
my code is..

```js
var response =[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Recipe": "recipe1",
        "gt14": "50",
        "gt13": "100",
        "gt11": "450",
        "gt150": "11",
        "gt16": "123"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Recipe": "recipe2",
        "gt14": "420",
        "gt13": "1000",
        "gt11": "140",
        "gt150": "110",
        "gt16": "132"
    }
]
   var thead = "";
        var tbody = "";
        var columns = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(response[0]);
        columns.push("Apply", "Current Value");
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
          thead += "<th scope='col'>" + columns[i] + "</th>";
        }
        $("#recipeTableData thead tr").html(thead);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          var objValues = Object.values(response[i]);

          tbody += "<tr>";
          for (var j = 0; j < objValues.length; j++) {
            tbody += "<td scope='col'>" + objValues[j] + "</td>";
          }

          tbody +=
            "<td scope='col'><button onlick='btnApply(" +
            i +
            ")';>Apply</button></td>";
          tbody +=
            "<td scope='col'><button class='btnCurrent';>CurrentValue</button></td>";
          tbody += "</tr>";
        }
        $("#recipeTableData tbody ").html(tbody);
```

```html
 <table  id="recipeTableData" class="table table-bordered" >
  <thead>
    <tr>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/harshad-patson/pen/gOjyGoy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo in `onClick` inside button element and you havent defined `btnApply` function to the code these are two reasons why it was not working
take a look at corrected version

```js
var response =[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Recipe": "recipe1",
        "gt14": "50",
        "gt13": "100",
        "gt11": "450",
        "gt150": "11",
        "gt16": "123"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Recipe": "recipe2",
        "gt14": "420",
        "gt13": "1000",
        "gt11": "140",
        "gt150": "110",
        "gt16": "132"
    }
]
   var thead = "";
        var tbody = "";
        var columns = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(response[0]);
        columns.push("Apply", "Current Value");
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
          thead += "<th scope='col'>" + columns[i] + "</th>";
        }
        $("#recipeTableData thead tr").html(thead);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          var objValues = Object.values(response[i]);

          tbody += "<tr>";
          for (var j = 0; j < objValues.length; j++) {
            tbody += "<td scope='col'>" + objValues[j] + "</td>";
          }

          tbody +=
            "<td scope='col'><button onClick='btnApply("+i+")';>Apply</button></td>";
          tbody +=
            "<td scope='col'><button class='btnCurrent';>CurrentValue</button></td>";
          tbody += "</tr>";
        }
        $("#recipeTableData tbody").html(tbody);

        function btnApply(index){
            var row = response[index]
            console.log(row)
        }
```

```html
 <table  id="recipeTableData" class="table table-bordered" >
  <thead>
    <tr>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```